# jQuery JSON array conversion

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert
`['peter', 'pan','Michael','peter','pan']`
into
`[{'peter':2},{'pan':2},{'michael':1}]`
which counts the number of time a name appears, then print it out.

but `names[name] = 0;` doesn't work, neither does `names[name] = names[name] + 1;`

Comment: This has nothing to do with either jQuery or JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = ['peter', 'pan','Michael','peter','pan'];
// create a temporary mapping holder.
var tmp = {};
for (var ii=0; ii < data.length; ii++) {
   // set the key to 0 if it doesn't exist.
   if (!(tmp[data[ii]])) {
      tmp[data[ii]]  = 0;
   }
   tmp[data[ii]] ++;
}
// create the output array.
var output = [];
for (var key in tmp)
{
    var pObj = {};
    pObj[key] = tmp[key];
    output.push(pObj);
}
```

You can do this all in a single loop, but I thought it might be easier to understand by breaking it up.